# Nesting tags with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I would like to use jQuery to create this HTML:

```
<a href="link"> <img src="image path"> </a>`
```

Somebody out there that know how this can be achieved?
This is how my code looks now:

```
projects.forEach((project) => {
    let projectContainer = $('<div>').addClass('Project').appendTo($('.ProjectsContainer'));

    $('<h1>').text(project.Title).appendTo(projectContainer);
    $('<img>').addClass('DesktopImg').attr('src', project.DesktopImage).appendTo(projectContainer);
    $('<img>').addClass('MobileImg').attr('src', project.MobileImage).appendTo(projectContainer);
    $('<p>').text(project.Description).appendTo(projectContainer);
    $('<a>').addClass('ViewBtb').attr('href', project.GitHubLink).text('GitHub Repo').appendTo(projectContainer);
});
```

I would like to nest those two image tags into a link tag so that I can click on them.

Comment: Create the `<a>` first and append image to it instead of the parent container

Comment: Thanks you for the help :)

Comment: There are many jQuery methods for inserting and wrapping elements. Have you looked into them? What's your _specific_ question?